# Two ListViews, 1 Activity - and Pull to Refresh?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, pull-to-refresh

I am not sure how to go about doing this.  This is my requirements for an `Activity`:

1. Header
2. `ListView` of 10 items
3. Header
4. `ListsView` of 10 items

The `ListViews`are coming from two different data sources and may have two different row layouts.  So I am thinking I need to make two Custom `adapter` classes (two `getView()'s`, etc).

Here's the kicker, I want to be able to pull-to-refresh the whole list and update both `ListViews`.  If that is too much, I'll settle with a refresh button (that Google seems to prefer anyway); currently I use `com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView`

Is this possible?  If so, what is best steps to make this work?

Comment: will your both list always contain 10 items??

Comment: Yeah, it will be statically set.  The Database call will basically say "Limit 10" or 15 or 20, etc.  Whatever I choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very much possible. 
Approach can be one **ScrollView with one LinearLayout child(vertical orientation)**.
Now two ListView as child views for linearlayout. 
As you said already,you will need two adaptors(with different row layout). Each list can have its own Header View.

For PulltoRefresh functionality,
 **[you can have a look at pulltorefresh library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)** 
This allows you to make any View as pull to refresh. As i explained above you need ScrollView as root view, So you need to use **PullToRefreshScrollView** from above library.

Comment: Good idea on pull-to-refresh on non-ListView items.  The one I am using does that as well.  Thank you very much, you gave me some ideas!  Last question:  in the activity, I can't really do `getListView()` -- how do I differentiate them since I need to set two different `adapters`?

Comment: you need to give different ids to each ListView in your layout xml say             "android:id="@+id/listView_1" & "android:id="@+id/listView_2" and use         ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_1) for finding it your activity.

Answer (score 1):

MergeAdapter will help you to merge any number of headers and adapters into a single one. So basically in your activity only one ListView is needed and this ListView should be use a merge adapter with two headers and two custom adapters.

[Merge Adapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge)